# c# asp Textbox Text does only change from Code behind when Textbox is readonly

Tags: c#

I'm absolutliy confused.
I try to Change the default Text for a Textbox.

Here a simple Code to reproduce the Problem.

TextBox Textbox1 and the label become updated on any click to the Button.
Textbox var will never get updated. Only on first PageLoad.

The Problem is, I have to add my Textboxes from Code behind and not in aspx Page.

Any Ideas whats going on and how I can get it working?

```
%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="tbtester.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div >

        <asp:Panel ID="mypanel" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
            </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

    namespace tbtester
    {
        public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox var = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox();
                //if (!this.Page.IsPostBack)
                Label test = new Label();

                mypanel.Controls.Add(test);
                mypanel.Controls.Add(var);

                var.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
                test.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();

                var.ReadOnly = false;

                TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();



            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable its `read only` flag `before` adding it to your `panel`:

```
     TextBox var = new TextBox();
     var.ReadOnly = false;
     mypanel.Controls.Add(var);
```

Comment: Readonly is disabled by default. The Line was only for debugging. When I enable Readonly, the textbox will become updated but the User cannot change the Value in his Browser. Its a little bit crazy.